# fgets() doesn't ask for input the second time in a row

Tags: c, fgets

I was writing code which called 2 different functions which us fgets(), but I noticed the second fgets() was skipped over. I tried making a test file to fix this,but I noticed even when writing stupidly simple code it still won't wait for me to type the second time around. EDIT: changed the [3] into a [4], still doesn't work though.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char I[4];
    
    fgets(I,3,stdin);
    
    printf("%s",I);
    
    fgets(I,3,stdin);
    
    printf("%s",I);
}
```

Comment: If you type more characters than can fit in the given argument, the rest are left in the input buffer for the next call to read.

Comment: 3 is ridiculously small for a line buffer. Try `I[100]` instead of  `I[3]` and `fgets(I, 100, stdin)` instead of `fgets(I,3,stdin)`, Also call things by their name `I` is a very poor name, why not call it `line`?

Comment: `int main(void)`

Comment: I changed the [3] thing but that didn't fix it

Comment: What input are you providing?

Comment: 2 character strings like A1 or C5

Comment: Change `fgets()` to `fgets(I, 4, stdin)`

Comment: Oh yeah that worked, why tho? I thought that it would need just 3 (1 for newline 2 for the actual characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that it would need [just 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692282/fgets-doesnt-ask-for-input-the-second-time-in-a-row/67692932#comment119650869_67692282)

To fully read in `"A1\n"`, `fgets()` needs at least 4.  3 for the *line*<sup>1</sup> read and 1 for the appended *null character* to form a *string*.

> The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s.  No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array. C2x dr § 7.21.7.2 2

With input `"A1\n"` and `fgets(I,3,stdin);`, `fgets()` reads the `"A1"`, leaving the `'"\n"` for the next `fgets()`.   That 2nd `fgets()` returns promptly as it read a `'\n'`.

---

Instead

- Use a generous buffer.  I recommend 2x whatever you think the max sane input will be.
- Pass into `fgets()` the size of the buffer.
- Check return
- Print with sentinels for clarity

.

```
// char I[4];
// fgets(I,3,stdin);
// printf("%s",I);

char I[100];
if (fgets(I, sizeof I, stdin)) {
  printf("<%s>\n", I);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In C, "each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character."

Answer (score 1):

The prototype of `fgets()` defines it as, `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)`,with `n - 1` being the maximum number of characters to be read, for an input like:

`A1\n`, you have three characters and the **NULL** byte, so `A1\n\0`.

By setting `n` to **3**, you tell `fgets()` that it will read **2** characters at most plus `\0` to terminate the string. Therefore, the newline (`\n`) character is left in the buffer, later to be consumed by the next `fgets()` call.

So changing `fgets(I, 3, stdin)` to `fgets(I, 4, stdin)` should fix your problem. You might also want to consider checking the return value of `fgets()` in case it returns a **NULL** pointer.

Comment: "By setting n to 3, you tell fgets() that it will read 3 characters at most. " --> no.  It will read 2 characters at most.  "The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s."

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Correct, I meant to say 2 + the NULL byte, will adjust.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because the keyboard buffer is not cleared. Basically in the first `fgets` if the keyboard input reaches the limit of the input buffer size, the rest will be read by the next `fgets`.

This example works according to what you went through with the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void flushBuffer() {
    int ch;
    while (((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && (ch != '\n'));
}

int main()
{
    char I[3];

    fgets(I, sizeof(I), stdin);
    printf("\n%s",I);

    if ( strchr( I, '\n' ) == NULL )
    {
        flushBuffer();
    }

    fgets(I, sizeof(I), stdin);
    printf("\n%s",I);

    return 0;
}
```

Another point is to use the `sizeof` operator to indicate the size of the vector.
As for the size of the vector, it really is quite small, if possible put a larger value according to your need.

Comment: `sizeof` isn't a function.

Comment: Thanks, adjusted.

Comment: Note that in the line `while (((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && (ch != '\n'));`, one set of parentheses are unnecessary. You can simply write `while ( (ch=getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' );` instead. See [C operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for more informatiom. However, that does not make it wrong. If you find it easier to read and clearer that way, then you can keep it that way.

Comment: I agree, I rewrote the text. Thanks.

Comment: I see one problem with your code: Your code seems to assume that the first line of input will be too large to fit in the buffer, and then calls `flushBuffer` to discard the rest of the line. But how will your code behave if it **does** fit into the buffer? In that case, `flushBuffer` will discard the second line of input. Is this intended?

Comment: I agree. The solution it presents was based on the code and the problem that was presented. Looking further, I saw that it is possible to use `setbuf(stdin, NULL)` after `fgets` instead of the `flushBuffer` method.

Comment: I severely doubt that `setbuf( stdin, NULL )` is the solution to your problem. See [this page](https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/setbuf-stdin-null-cant-work-why.439102/) for an explanation of the reasons. I was thinking of a simpler solution. Instead of unconditionally executing `flushBuffer();`, you could do the following: `if ( strchr( I, '\n' ) == NULL ) flushBuffer();`

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I will adopt this solution.